# jQuery on click on everything but a div and it's children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something when I click anywhere, except when I click a  div and it's children. This is what I've tried so far, but it's not working (clicking on it's children still executes what is within the brackets.

```
$('body').on('click', '* :not(#calculator)',  function(e){
```

I cannot use something like this:

[jQuery - Select everything except a single elements and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173055/jquery-select-everything-except-a-single-elements-and-its-children)

```
$("body > *").not("body > #elementtokeep").remove();
```

Because the `.not` function is not something I can put inside the `.on()` function.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: add an class to the childs, and check on that?

Comment: Don't you think it cuold be a lot simpler? The div I want to exclude is pretty big, and chances are I'll forget to add that specific class every time.

Comment: Mayby you've got something on this??? http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use not with a comma to have both selectors: the element itself and the elements children

```
jQuery(document.body).on("click", ":not(#calculator, #calculator *)", function(e){ 
    console.log(this); 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});​​​​​​​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALANT/)

Answer (score 7):

You could check inside the function for the element in question:

```
$('body').click( function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).is("#calculator") || $("#calculator").has(e.target).length ) {
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: the element bubbles, that's why it gets triggered on the #calculator element, you have to check if the target is a child of #calculator or the calculator element #itself.

Comment: @Bax You're right, updated my answer to check for descendants too.

Comment: Yes, that's awesome :) I do think I prefer epascarello's answer though, because it keeps my code a little cleaner :)

Comment: Isn't `!$("#calculator").has(e.target)` always `false`? Shouldn't it be `($("#calculator").has(e.target).length > 0)`?

Comment: @Micah you're completely right. jQuery has() `Reduce the set of matched elements`, it does NOT return a boolean. see http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: @Micah I submitted an edit with the corrected answer, using javascript truthy/falsy values, we can simplify the expression to `$("#calculator").has(e.target).length` see http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough requirement to add commend, so I need to ask my question here to **@epascarello**. When I made few children, A and B still affected. I am not sure I am wrong or not, but I really want to get solution.

```
jQuery(document.body).on("click", ":not(#calculator, #calculator *)", function(e){ 
    console.log(this); 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    alert('test');
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ALANT/28/)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
$('body').on('click', '* :not(#calculator)',  function(e){

});​
```

You can use (this version is preferred as it is more performant)

```
$("body").on("click", ":not(#calculator, #calculator *)", function(e){ 

});​
```

or

```
$("body :not(#calculator, #calculator *)").on("click", function(e){ 

});​
```

Comment: Your answer defeats the purpose of `on`. Yes it would work, but you are adding way to many click handlers to the page.