# Jquery - Hide iframe content on main page body click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

In my page having two iframe **iframe-menu** and **iframe-content**.
I want to hide **iframe-content** elements ('.options') on anywhere click event in entire page i.e outside of .options div.

**Main Page :**

```
<body>
   <iframe src="menu.html" id="iframe-menu" height="100%"></iframe>
   <iframe src="content.html" id="iframe-content" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

**content.html in iframe-content**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="options">Hello</div>
</div>
```

I have use a jquery code. But it's working only when click on current iframe.

```
$(document.body).click(function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (!target.parents().andSelf().is('.options')) { 
        $('.options').hide();
    }
});
```

I want to hide div.options on anywhere click on the main page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery on click on everything but a div and it's children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690313/jquery-on-click-on-everything-but-a-div-and-its-children)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use `.hide()`

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('.options')) { 
        $(".test").contents().find(".options").hide();
    }
});
```

Try setting a class name for the iframe & hide the element using `.content().find()`

Check JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8eor228/7/)

Comment: Your code work for main page element hiding and I want to hide element inside the iframe.

Comment: Edited my answer!